# Am I accessing these resource files in java incorrectly?

Tags: java, eclipse, path

I have two classes. One is intended to be a common library and another a client that consumes from the library.

The  library is structured as below:

```
public class Library
{



    public Library()
    {
         String pathToResourceA="src/main/resources/A.xls";// A.xls is present within resources
         String key="apples";

         Resource res= loadResourceBasedOnDoc(pathToResource,key);
         ...//process resource

    }

}
```

It's corresponding test class

```
public class LibraryTest
{
    @Test
    public void testLibrary()
    {
        new Library();// works as expected- the test passes and the resource is loaded.//ie. A.xls is found in the right place

    }

}
```

However, when I try to access the library from my client in the following manner

```
import packagename.Library

public class Client{

    Library lib;
    public Client()
    {
        lib= new Library();// throws a FileNotFoundException!

    }

}
```

I get a FileNotFoundException. I'm guessing this is something to do with defining the right value to `pathToResourceA` in class A but cant figure out what it is. Any thoughts would be appreciated. Thanks!

Code for `loadResourcesBasedonDoc`

```
protected Resource loadResourceBasedOnDoc(String filename,String password)
{
InputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = new FileInputStream(filename);
    //further in is processed...
```

Comment: can you post the code for the  loadResourceBasedOnDoc method?

Comment: @EJK Ive added what the code does on a high level.

Comment: Your comment "A.xls is present within resources".  Could you please elaborate?  Is A.xls a file on the file system, or is it a file included in the library's JAR file?

Comment: `A.xls` is a file on the file system. `src/main/resources/A.xls` is the path to the file relative to `Library`. The whole idea is to not have `A.xls` in multiple projects and only in the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using relative file paths:

```
String pathToResourceA="src/main/resources/A.xls";// A.xls is present within resources
```

This is then processed in the loadResourceBasedOnDoc method as follows:

```
in = new FileInputStream(filename);
```

This call looks for the file (src/main/resources/A.xls) on the file system.  Because the path is relative, it looks for the file in a directory that is **relative to the current working directory**.  In your unit test, the current working directory is probably the directory from which the test is launched.  Assuming that is the root of your project, the test likely finds A.xls on the file system within your project.

To solve this, I recommend using full pathnames in the loadResourceBasedOnDoc as follows:

```
String programLaunchDir = System.getProperty("user.dir")
in = new FileInputStream(programLaunchDir + File.separator  + filename);
```

The *user.dir* system property should be the current working directory.  So if you can enforce that the program is launched from that dir, you are all set.  Otherwise, you might want to wrap you program in a batch file or shell script that passes the directory to the program.

Comment: Makes sense. However, I think the better approach would be to pass `loadResourceBasedOnDoc(rootPath+"/"+filename,key)` in the initial call. Plus, the whole gist of my question was to ask **how** one could get the right value for `rootPath`. Can you add that to the answer and confirm my approach? Thanks!